Why am i getting a HttpError 'A Location is required error'
I am trying to run some code to update a few of the question titles in a form that I am creating. I am running the code below and receiving the error: 'A location is required'. I have tried to look at documentation to fix this but have not had much luck.
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient import discovery
import requests
import time
import os
import pandas as pd

os.environ['OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT'] = '1'

# from googleapiclient import discovery

# Define the scope and credentials
SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms.body"]
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'credentials.json' # Replace with the actual path to your credentials file

# Load the service account credentials
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

# Create a service object for the Google Forms API
form_service = discovery.build(
    'forms', 'v1',
    credentials=credentials,
    discoveryServiceUrl='https://forms.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1',
    static_discovery=False
)

#Form Meta Data

FORM_ID = 'MYFORMIDHERE' #week 2 form

# Retrieve the current form metadata
form_metadata = form_service.forms().get(formId=FORM_ID).execute()
print(form_metadata)

# Get the form items
items = form_metadata.get('items', [])

# Prepare a batch update request to update questions
update_requests = []

# Print the current items in the form
print("Current items in the form:")
for item in items:
    print(item)

# Start from the second item to skip the 'Name' question
for index, item in enumerate(items[1:], start=1):
    if index - 1 >= len(nfl_sched_cols):
        print(f"Skipping index {index}, out of bounds for DataFrame")
        continue

    if 'title' in item and 'questionItem' in item:
        # Extract existing title and question
        existing_title = item['title']
        question_info = item['questionItem']['question']
        
        # Get the corresponding row from your DataFrame
        row = nfl_sched_cols.iloc[index - 1]
        print(f"Updating item {index}: {existing_title} with row data: {row}")

        # New title
        new_title = f"AWAY: {row['away_team'].upper()} ({row['away_record']}) VS HOME: {row['home_team'].upper()} ({row['home_record']})"
        
        # Add an update request for each item
        update_requests.append({
            "updateItem": {
                "item": {
                    "itemId": item['itemId'],
                    "title": new_title,
                    "questionItem": {
                        "question": question_info
                    }
                },
                "updateMask": "title"
            }
        })

# Print the batch update request for debugging
print("Batch update request:")
for req in update_requests:
    print(req)

# Batch update the form
if update_requests:
    batch_update_request = {
        "requests": update_requests
    }
    try:
        updated_form = form_service.forms().batchUpdate(formId=FORM_ID, body=batch_update_request).execute()
        print("Form questions updated successfully!")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred during batch update: {e}")
else:
    print("No items found to update.")

The error I am receiving is as follows:

An error occurred during batch update: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://forms.googleapis.com/v1/forms/1Wzz0_Et5fsk068m64dljRp9pWmgh7R-WJz2xCpIgCSs:batchUpdate?alt=json returned "A Location is required". Details: "A Location is required">

It points to this part of the code:
        updated_form = form_service.forms().batchUpdate(formId=FORM_ID, body=batch_update_request).execute()

I have added error handling and have been able to pin point where the code errors out but am not sure how to handle it.

In your showing script, how about the following modification?
From:
update_requests.append({
    "updateItem": {
        "item": {
            "itemId": item['itemId'],
            "title": new_title,
            "questionItem": {
                "question": question_info
            }
        },
        "updateMask": "title"
    }
})

To:
update_requests.append({
    "updateItem": {
        "item": {
            "itemId": item['itemId'],
            "title": new_title,
            "questionItem": {
                "question": question_info
            }
        },
        "updateMask": "title",
        "location": {"index": index}, # <--- Added
    }
})

Reference:

UpdateItemRequest


This is fantastic. Thank you so much. Appreciate you linking the reference as well!

@John Tayson Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.
